# Script to safely backup sqlite3 database on ubuntu 12.04 sever

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite

We want to run a cron job for safely backing up sqlite3 db on ubuntu 12.04 server. The database may be locked by other apps when performing backup and we need the solution to be safe with this situation. There is backup api and we are not sure how to use it. The solution should be able to backup the entire db or even better incrementally. What we plan to do is to backup into a file on the same server. We are looking for a script which can plug into cron scheduler with none or a little modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The backup API can be invoked with the `.backup` command of the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command-line tool.

To wait for other apps to unlock the database, you have to set a timeout with the `.timeout` command:

```
sqlite3 my.db <<EOF
.timeout 20000
.backup backup.db
EOF
```

SQLite has no incremental backup functionality.

Comment: a very clean script! what happens if during '.backup backup.db' there is a writing request on the db? Is .timeout 20000 going to clean up locking and make db ready for backup?

Comment: When another app tries to wait, it will wait according to its own timeout setting. The timeout value just specifies the upper bound of the time the database should wait for the other app to finish its access; 20000 milliseconds might or might not be enough for you.